# Tensorflow: 'module' object has no attribute 'RunMetaData'

Tags: python, tensorflow, attributeerror

I am trying to get GPU/CPU time stats using tensorflow timeline module but on

```
 run_metadata = tf.RunMetaData()
```

It gives following error.

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RunMetaData'
```

I am using `0.10.0rc0` version. 
I also go to `tensorflow/python/client/timeline.py` to actually see the function definition but It didn't exist there. 
P.S: I have imported `from tensorflow.python.client import timeline`
 
 [Code snippet]

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_conv, y_))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.RunOutputs()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
```

[ERROR SNIPPET]

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0dd6887f3319> in <module>()
     90 
     91 run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
---> 92 run_metadata = tf.RunMetaData()
     93 sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
     94 

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RunMetaData'
```

Comment: I guess the immediate thing to try in any case would be a more recent version (0.12.1). If that doesn't help or isn't doable, could you post a snippet of code which causes this error?

Comment: I updated the question with snippets. I can't update the version for now. Its kinda problem.

Comment: Oh, I thought this was some TensorFlow component calling a function that doesn't exist. Do you just mean `RunMetadata` (lowercase "d")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to install TensorFlow 0.12.0 or higher.